# Table of contents spacing problem xx.xx

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a spacing problem with the table of content list. Any tips?

[image]

I am using LuaLatex, no usepackages to manage table of contents and I am writing in the `\documentclass[11pt]{article}`. The problem seems to occur with the sub- and subsubsections.

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ. Next, please tell us if you're using a package, such as `tocloft`, to manage the appearance of the table of contents. Finally, please also tell us which types of sectioning headers we're looking at: Are they chapters, sections, and subsections, or are they sections, subsections, and subsubsections?

Comment: Many thanks for providing some additional pieces of information. Do please also reveal which document class you employ. (It's the argument of the `\documentclass` directive.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's look at the way LaTeX does this stuff.  In the highest-level sectioning entry (`\@section` in the `article` class), the value of `\@tempdima` sets the width of interest here.

For the lower levels of sectioning, it is the 3rd argument to `\@dottedtocline` where the field width is passed:

```
\newcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
```

So, depending on what class you have and what package tools you are using, the approach will vary only in the specific details.

---

Case 1) If you are using `tocloft`, it provides length macros instead of hardwired numbers to use for these dimensions.  Thus, changing the length macros is sufficient to effect the change.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{3em}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{3em}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{1in}
\section{Section First}
\subsection{SubSection First}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection First}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out the three `\addtolength` commands...

[image]

---

Case 2) If you are using the `article` class, but not using `tocloft`, you can add, here 2em, to the number-label-width by patching 3 low-level macros directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\l@section}{{1.5em}}{{3.5em}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\l@subsection}{{2.3em}}{{4.3em}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\l@subsubsection}{{3.2em}}{{5.2em}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{1in}
\section{Section First}
\subsection{SubSection First}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection First}
\end{document}
```

---

Case 3) `book` class, without `tocloft`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\l@chapter}{{1.5em}}{{3.5em}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\l@section}{{2.3em}}{{4.3em}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\l@subsection}{{3.2em}}{{5.2em}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{1in}
\chapter{Chapter First}
\section{Section First}
\subsection{SubSection First}
\end{document}
```

---

Case 4) `scrartcl` without `tocloft`, here doing a direct redefinition, rather than just a patch.  Again, it is `\@tempdima` in `\l@section` and the 3rd argument to `\@dottedtocline` in the lower sectioning macros that are being revised.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty{\@secpenalty}%
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \sectfont
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{4.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{3.8em}{5.2em}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{1in}
\section{Section First}
\subsection{SubSection First}
\subsubsection{SubSubSection First}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for great advice! Is there an easy way to fix the same problem for LoF and LoT?

Comment: @HaraldKyllingstad I'd have to look into it...but I would suggest to ask it as a separate question altogether, rather than as an extension to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that uses the `tocloft` package. Note the use of the `\addtolength` instruction to increase the values of the length parameters `\cftsubsecnumwidth`, `\cftsubsubsecindent`, and `\cftsubsubsecnumwidth`. Feel free to adjust the argument of `\addtolength` to suit your preferences.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}  % optional
\setmainfont{Fira Sans Book} % select a suitable sans-serif font

\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength\cftsubsecnumwidth{0.5em}% default value: 1.5em
\addtolength\cftsubsubsecindent{0.5em}
\addtolength\cftsubsubsecnumwidth{0.5em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\setcounter{section}{10} % just for this example
\setcounter{subsection}{7}

\subsection{Betong i herdet tilstand}
\subsubsection{Densitet}
\subsubsection{Trykkfasthet}
\subsubsection{Kontroll av \dots}
\subsubsection{3-Punktstest}
\subsubsection{Metode for bruk \dots}
\subsection{Fuktinhold \dots}
\subsection{Partikkel-matriks modellen}
\subsubsection{Utst\o ping og \dots}
\subsection{Dimenjonering}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for great advice! Is there an easy way to fix the same problem for LoF and LoT?

Comment: @HaraldKyllingstad - Yes. Depending on what you want to achieve, you'll need to modify the length parameters `\cfttabnumwidth`, `\cftfignumwidth`, `\cfttabindent`, and `\cftfigindent`. If you need further information in order to get started, please post a new query.